# Recentering map when geolocation marker gets near edge of viewport

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a small volunteer project for a local land conservancy that shows their KML map data for the trails they maintain, and shows a marker where people are hiking on the trail.

I need the map to recenter when the marker gets near the edge of the viewport.

Not finding sample code for this.

Here is what I have currently for the map drawing itself:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<script src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocationmarker/src/geolocationmarker-compiled.js"></script>
<script>
  var map, GeoMarker;
  var ojai = new google.maps.LatLng(34.4487119,-119.247359);

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: ojai,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);


         /* Trail KML Data Layer
         ------------------------------------------------- */
         var trailLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://example.com/trail.kml', 
            preserveViewport: true // don't resize viewport to fit KML data
            });

          ovlcLayer.setMap(map);



    GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();
    GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({fillColor: '#808080'});

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
      map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
      //map.panTo(this.getPosition());
      map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
      alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
    });

    GeoMarker.setMap(map);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  if(!navigator.geolocation) {
    alert('Your browser does not support geolocation');
  }  

     </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

When the geolocation is updated, check to see if it is within the map bounds, recenter the map if it isn't.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
  if (!map.getBounds().contains(GeoMarker.getPosition()))
  map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks in the right direction. Copy and pasted directly into page. Tested on iPhone 5 and Android (5.1) and map did not recenter in either case. I have connected the android  phone to the USB remote debugging in Chrome and don't see any direct console errors. However `uncaught TypeError in js?v=3:30` and it says that `getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins`

Comment: current direct testing link: [trail friend](http://www.claritywebworks.co/ovlc/go9.html)